# Running shell commands in a swift script

Tags: swift, shell, zsh

I am looking for a solutuion to run shell commands in a Swift script.

Here is my code:

```
func shellEnv(_ command: String) -> String {
    let task = Process()
    let pipe = Pipe()
    
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.standardError = pipe
    task.arguments = ["-c", command]
    task.launchPath = "/bin/zsh"
    task.launch()
    
    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
    
    return output
}
```

It works with built-in commands but it cannot deal with commands like "brew", "node" and other commands that were installed manually.

So how can I solve it?

Comment: And why can’t it deal with brew for instance, what happens?

Comment: I think you need to pass “-l” to make it a “login shell”, one which loads your personal confit files, including the ones that set your PATH

Comment: @Alexander Aww. That's a great shortcut compared to my clumsy answer. I'm still a shell newbie...

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `PATH` environment variable for the `task`. This has been set in your terminal, which is why you are able to do `brew` and `node` and other cool things *directly*, without specifying their full path.

You can see what this is set to in your terminal by doing:

```
echo $PATH
```

and it will print something like (for me it has a bunch more things. This is only an excerpt):

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

If you copy and paste the entire output of `echo $PATH`, and put it into the `environment` property of `task`, then you will be able to use the same commands in your swift script as in your terminal.

```
task.environment = ["PATH": "<paste the output here>"]
```

As Alexander said in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68300352/running-shell-commands-in-a-swift-script/68300594#comment120710667_68300352), another way is to add the `l` option. Here is a MCVE:

```
#!/usr/bin/swift

// main.swift
import AppKit

func shellEnv(_ command: String) -> String {
    let task = Process()
    let pipe = Pipe()
    
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.standardError = pipe
    task.arguments = ["-cl", command]
    task.launchPath = "/bin/zsh"
    task.launch()
    
    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
    
    return output
}

print(shellEnv("brew list")) // assuming you have brew
```

To run, `chmod +x main.swift` then `./main.swift`, and you will see all your homebrew packages listed.

Comment: @IvanEFan Did you try Alexander's simpler solution? Use `-cl` instead of `-c`.

Comment: I have tried that but I still get "command not found" :(

Comment: @IvanEFan Works for me though. Can you describe the full list of steps, and a [mcve], to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @IvanEFan I added my own minimal reproducible example. Can you try that? Does that work for you?

Comment: The MCVE works fine without -l if you run it as a script from the command line since you are already logged in then.

Comment: That works, but when I put it to a SwiftUI Application, I will get command not found

Comment: Is your project perhaps sandboxed? Maybe this is about another level of access, I have no problem running the code in my small command line tool project (but with -l then)

Comment: @IvanEFan Oh I interpreted "Swift script" in your question as "Swift as a scripting language", but it turns out you just meant "Swift programming language" in general? In that case, Joakim Danielson could be right. Check your signing and capabilities tab in your project settings. See if app sandbox is enabled. If it is, remove it.

Comment: @IvanEFan If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!